# How do I store the time part of NSDateComponents?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, type-conversion, nsdatecomponents

I want to store times type value (but not the date) in Core Data. Which data type should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible options:

- Three integer attributes for hour, minutes, seconds.
- One string attribute for "HH:MM:SS".
- One integer attribute for the number of seconds since midnight.

The best representation depends on what type of queries involving the time you want to
execute. The first option is better if you want to search for a given hour, minute or second. The other options are better if you have to search for time intervals.

Comment: Seconds don't matter. To clarify the question: It is a pill reminder app. The user sets the time of consuming a medicament in his settings and the goal is to remind hime every day at his chosen time.

Comment: @mradlmaier: Then probably any solution would work. With separate hour/minutes attributes you can easily create NSDateComponents and a from there an NSDate (for the current day).

Comment: Actually the time is not what is queried for. The data structure should be something like this: morning --> 8:00, noon --> 12:00, etc. where as the user presets if morning for him will be 7:00 or 7:30 or 8:00 etc. And the query will ask "Get the morning time" or "Get the noon time"...

Comment: @mradlmaier: There are many possible representations. For example an integer 0, 1, 2 (representing morning, noon, evening) and two integers for hour and minute.

Comment: OK, the general idea is not to use NSDate, but integers instead. (And maybe some ordinal integer to support sorting by time in case I store each component as a different attribute)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would probably be to convert it to an HHMMSS format, either as an integer or a string.  NSDate isn't appropriate because it is stored as a interval since an epoch (seconds since 1970)

Comment: Not important here, but the date is stored as number of seconds since the "reference date" 1 January 2001, GMT.

Answer (score 0):

The date portion of an NSDate is inherently part of time. NSDate is a NSTimeInterval number of seconds positive or negative since the reference date. With a locale and a timezone you can get an appropriate localized display string on the fly. 
In most cases it makes far more sense to store the number behind the NSDate returned by timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
It's small and portable and correct. 
Then recreate an NSDate with dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:

Then use an NSDateFormatter with NSLocale and NSTimeZone to get an appropriate value for display to users.

It's an unwieldy and cumbersome set of tools that actually help you do it right. 
The good news is all the effort you expend in doing this pays off in making it easier next time and giving you code that will do the right thing and have a backing value that is actually really easy to store and manipulate. 
Additionally by using the API correctly you will lose no precision and have more possibilities open to you.

Trying to do it with format strings alone seems easy and simple but is the road to bad code.

Comment: If you say seconds don't matter for an app that is supposed to do reminders of any kind you are not really understanding calendrical calculation and how much Cocoa gives you to do it right.

Comment: You are generally right. But in this question "09:00" means 9 o'clock in the morning on *any* day and therefore is not an absolute point in time. So in this particular case it makes more sense (in my opinion) to store hours/minutes instead of NSDate.

Comment: Interesting. Is it being used as a label?  Just curious how it would sync to any time zone and if it makes sense per locale. You might not even be targeting many locales though.